# Create an arbitary table like object for jOOQ unit testing

Tags: java, sql, unit-testing, mocking, jooq

I have an issue using jOOQ's `MockDataProvider` to mock a SQL JOIN in a unit test.

The JOIN implemented with jOOQ selects a single column containing UUIDs. Thus the result type is `Result<Record1<UUID>>`. In the associated unit test I would like to mock this result using the `MockDataProvider`, but I can't find a proper way to initialize the `Result`, as I can't find a way to create a table like object I could pass to the `newResult` method. I know that there are some `table` methods in `DSL`, but the signatures just seem to be wrong for my use case.

Also as the unit test is not runnable at this point, I'm not sure that the way I create the UUID field is correct.

This is my code:

```
private class MyProvider implements MockDataProvider {

    @Override
    public MockResult[] execute(final MockExecuteContext ctx) throws SQLException {
        final MockResult[] mockResults = new MockResult[1];
        final DSLContext db = DSL.using(SQLDialect.POSTGRES);
        final Result<Record1<UUID>> result = db.newResult(<some table object here>);
        final Field<UUID> uuidField = DSL.fieldByName(UUID.class, "uuid");
        final Record1<UUID> record = db.newRecord(uuidField);
        record.setValue(uuidField, ID);
        result.add(record);
        mockResults[0] = new MockResult(1, result);

        return mockResults;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this is essentially the same question as the one on the jOOQ User Group here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jooq-user/h4pfIHjmBpo

In summary, there is a method that is going to be added to jOOQ 3.4 (with [issue #3139](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3139)), to help you create such `Result` objects for arbitrary `Record` types. In the mean time (before jOOQ 3.4 is released), you will have to resort to creating a new `org.jooq.impl.ResultImpl` via reflection.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So I'll wait for 3.4 :-)